# FitsPage replacement

Tags: itext

I've recently upgraded iTextsharp from version 4.0.4 to version 5.4.4

Overall I had to make very few modifications to my code, however one method no longer exists, and I can't find a replacement method.

```
PdfWriter.FitsPage
```

I was using this method to check if a `PdfPTable` would on a page, and do things accordingly.

Is there a newer method that does this?

The only solution I could find involved simulating the action of adding the table and seeing if it fits, but I find it hard to believe a single line call would have been replaced with a more complex set of code.

Comment: I don't have time for code but you are now encouraged to use a `ColumnText` object in simulation mode to see if something fits. See http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/PdfWriter-FitsPage-tp2156208.html and http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/ColumnText-AddElement-and-simulated-Go-td1155.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, I understand there is new code that can perform what I'm trying to do. My question is, is the only replacement literally a replacement of one line of code to a dozen or more lines of code?

Comment: According to a thread by the author of iText from 7 years ago there were bugs reported with that older method and I think that it just had too many edge cases to support. Instead, they moved to a method that, albeit more complex, was also more accurate and provable. http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/iText-2-0-5-PDFWriter-FitsPage-method-marked-deprecated-td2154113.html#a2154114